# WPF: What is more easy is convinient to develop dynamically?

Tags: wpf, dynamic, user-interface, datagrid, grid

I have a DataGrid (dataGrid1) where records can be added and deleted.

Based on that dataGrid1, I want to make a new Grid with buttons in it based on ID and Types'. Cols will also have to given a DataSource of add dynamically, but that will be just while generating for the 1st time in Window_Loaded itself. Rows can be added/removed based on changes in dataGrid1. I want somethign like this :

[image]

On each Btn click, a new window will be opened for entry of the particular Type and for the particular ID. If the details are already entered, then the text of btn wil be "Update" else "Add".

What could be the best resource/control to perform this operations ? At present, I just did a Grid with 2 stable cols. Any ideas for the above to use Grid, DataGrid or something else. And adding/removing rows will be easy in which way and how.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should check the MVVM pattern (if you don't already know it), which offers exactly what you want: take a `DataGrid`, bind it to an `ObservableCollection` of whatever object you need, and adding an object to the collection will add a row to the `DataGrid` and vice versa.

Comment: @Damascus, I already have a DataGrid that is bind to an ObservableCollection. And based on the rows added/deleted in that DataGrid, I want rows in this grid. Can you show me an example of how to do the same adding buttons to the grid i.e. ObsevableCollection.

Comment: @Damascus, I will have buttons in all cols except 1st. Can I add Button to an object as source for the ObservableCollection<T> ? I mean, if T = Tender then can I have List<Button> member of it ?

Comment: You should NEVER use a IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> as an `ItemsSource`. The binding's goal is to avoid working on UI elements, you should rather use something like a `List<string>` as an `ItemsSource` and then define a `Template` for your `DataGrid` defining a button for each row. If you need a code snippet I'll be happy to post it as an answer, although I'm not sure it'd answer to your initial question anyway ^^

Comment: @Damascus, if you could provide a code snippet nothing like that. On each btn of different rows, I got to open a new window. For that also what would be more appropriate. I just found ICommand but am not ble to implement it. Pls provide code snippet as an answer. I am puzzled that teh cols will be dynamically added, with that also how to build ObservableCollection.

Comment: Done, I tried to make it as clear as possible =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let me try to take an example which is similar to your needs

Let's assume we use this class:

```
public class MyObject
{
   public int MyID;
   public string MyString;
   public ICommand MyCommand;
}
```

And we are willing to display a `DataGrid` listing the ID, and having as a second column a `Button`, with the property `MyString` as content, which, when clicked, launches the `ICommand` `MyCommand` which opens in a new window whatever you want.

Here is what you should have on the View side:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding MyID}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Buttons">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="{Binding MyString}" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This will show a `DataGrid` taking all the content in an `IEnumerable<MyObject>` named 'MyList', and shows two columns as defined before.

Now if you need to define the command.
First, I recommend you read [this introductory link to MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) and take the `RelayCommand` class (that's what we're gonna use for your problem)

So, in your `ViewModel`, the one which defines the `MyList`, here is how you should define some of the useful objects:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyList { get; set; }

// blah blah blah

public void InitializeMyList()
{
  MyList = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    MyList.Add(InitializeMyObject(i));
  }
}

public MyObject InitializeMyObject(int i)
{
  MyObject theObject = new MyObject();
  theObject.MyID = i;
  theObject.MyString = "The object " + i;
  theObject.MyCommand = new RelayCommand(param =< this.ShowWindow(i));
  return theObject
}

private void ShowWindow(int i)
{
  // Just as an exammple, here I just show a MessageBox
  MessageBox.Show("You clicked on object " + i + "!!!");
}
```

This should be enough to create whatever you want. As you can see, every `Button` will call a method (`ShowWindow`) which is defined to show your new window, do whatever you need inside. The `RelayCommand` is actually just here, as its name says, to relay the command fired by the button to a method which contains the execution logic.

And... I think that's all you need. Sorry for the late answer BTW

**EDIT - generating columns manually/dynamically**

The following code is part of a code I had to do when I had a similar problem.
My problem was, I needed to change the columns displayed every time a `ComboBox`'s `SelectedItem` would change. So I put this in a `SelectionChanged` event handler.
I don't know where exactly do you need to generate your columns, but I'll give you a general example.

Assume your `ItemsSource` is an `ObservableCollection<MyNewObject>`

`MyNewObject` is the following:

```
public class MyNewObject
{
   public IList<string> MyStrings { get; set; }
}
```

You should put somewhere in your code (should be when you need to generate the column) the following code, which is generating a number of columns equal to the length of the first `MyNewObject` from the list (note: this is in code-behind, and the `DataGrid` you're working on is named dataGrid)

```
ObservableCollection<MyNewObject> source = dataGrid.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<MyNewObject>;

if (source == null || source.Count == 0)
{
  return;
}
MyNewObject firstObject = source[0];

for(int i = 0; i < firstObject.MyStrings.Count; i++)
{
   // Creates one column filled with buttons for each string
   DataGridTemplateColumn columnToAdd = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
   columnToAdd.Width = 110; // I set a manual width, but you can do whatever you want
   columnToAdd.Header = "Header number " + i;

    // Create the template with a Button inside, bound to the appropriate string
    DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(Button));
    FrameworkElementFactory buttonElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));

    Binding binding = new Binding("MyStrings[" + i + "]");
    binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

    buttonElement.SetBinding(Button.ContentProperty, binding);

    // Do the same here for your command, or for whatever you want to do when the user clicks on this button

    dataTemplate.VisualTree = buttonElement;
    columnToAdd.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(columnToAdd);
}
```

This will create one column for each string found in the first object. Then, enhance it with whatever command or display trick you need!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your ICommand eg will definetely help me out. But my initial step to start the work relies at the same place. The cols will be added dynamically, and I don't know how many btn cols will be added. So in that case, MyString object got to be a collection. DataTemplate can also have N # of buttons, so again dynamic. The Content of button will be something like MyString[i]. Your code is really helpful and relevant to some extend. Just if you could show with a collection of MyString and binding that to the buttons would be great ans exactly where I am stuck. ICommand excell.

Comment: There is one thing I don't understand in your problem: Every object won't have the same number of buttons? How are you going to put it in a `DataGrid` if every object generates a different number of columns? By default, the WPF `DataGrid` generates one column for each property of your object. You mean that you'll have a variable number of properties?

Comment: The number of cols will depend on a Master. How many records master has, that many cols I got to have in the DataGrid. I will have the # of cols while initializing the DG in code. But my Source will have to have some sort of Collection only as don't know the master's # of records while design. How do I cope up with the Source obj with Property of Collection ?

Comment: Mmm... I'm not sure `DataGrid` is a good way to go. BUT, you can still prepare a workaround, I'll edit my post to show you how to do it

Comment: I will try out and see if things work out. I had tried earlier using like "MyStrings[i]", but the way you have mentioend is a bit different. Maybe this lisght difference in code help me achieve what I want. Will try and let you know.

Comment: your code helps me achieve the goal exactly as I am looking for. I was straight away using FrameworkElementFactory, without DataGridTemplateColumn &/or DataTemplate. With binding also was working like this - new Binding(string.Format("ButtonString[{0}]", i)); But your binding format i.e. "ButtonString[" + i + "]" also did the work - infact magic for me. Thanks a lot Damascus, for all the efforts and time you have been giving to question. I highly appreciate your support. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, that's what Stackoverflow is all about! And I know `DataGrids` can be a real pain as I developed a lot of Datagrid-related stuff so the best I can do is sharing my knowledge/pain about the subject.